# Execute exe after the installation is finish in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project, installation

I have created Setup Project in VS 2010.

I want to execute a exe after user clicks on Finsh/Close button.

What steps do I need to follow while creating a setup project.

I heared about custom action. But I dont have any idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Consult the vast resources of MSDN

- [HOW TO: Run an Executable File During a Windows Installer Installation by Using Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827018)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28VS.80%29.aspx)

or if you want a VBScript custom action (the exe is not part of your application and you do not want a new DLL file) see

[Visual Studio Setup - projects and custom actions](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/)